# Android - Animation won't start on button click

Tags: android, animation

I have an activity with a button and a basic view. When the button is clicked the animation should start. However, currently when the button is clicked nothing happens. If I move the code outside of the button and into the onCreate method the animation works, but I wan't it to happen when the button is clicked.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_map);

    final Button start_button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.main_button);
    final View inside_circle = findViewById(R.id.timer);

    start_button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {

            ScaleAnimation growAnim = new ScaleAnimation(1.0f, 3.68f, 1.0f, 3.68f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5F, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5F);
            growAnim.setDuration(3000);
            inside_circle.setAnimation(growAnim);
            growAnim.start();

        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use view.startAnimation() in onClick

```
 start_button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        ScaleAnimation growAnim = new ScaleAnimation(1.0f, 3.68f, 1.0f, 3.68f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5F, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5F);
        growAnim.setDuration(3000);            
        inside_circle.startAnimation(growAnim);        
    }
});
```